# Is code golf going to be opting into the voting reputation requirement test?

Tags: discussion, voting, reputation

Over on Meta Stack Exchange, there's a question asking for [sites to volunteer for a trial of removing reputation requirements for voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393127/391137).

Is that something the Code Golf and Coding Challenges community would be interested in?

(this question isn't in support of, or opposition against the trial)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## No

Code Golf participating would provide minimal useful information for Stack Exchange given our unique format, and it would solve a problem we really don't have (insufficient voting/interaction).

In fact, this would likely make our issues with FGITWing and drive-by voting on unimpressive answers even worse.